# Payment gateway on a simple HTML site

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I would need a payment gateway to my simple HTML site. It is not a webshop just a small food ordering website.

My goal:

1. Redirect user to a payment form (I will pass the total value)
2. After user does a successful payment, my site will be on focus again and the form (filled user data) will be posted to server side

- What is the easiest way to do that?
- What would I need to be able to do that? (PHP code + some payment gateway) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create pay button and add the code to your web page. In payment gateway you have option to set success url and cancel url. So once payment is successful customer will be redirected to the success url(which you set).